# Open path of a file in project explorer

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, project-explorer

Often I have the case that I have a file opened in the tabs like `item_category.xml` here:
[image]

The project explorer still shows something else. Any way to open the path to `item_category.xml` in the project explorer? I already checked the right-click menu of `item_category.xml`, but couldn't find a matching option.

Answer (score 1):

Use that symbol in the project explorer (shortcut: `Alt+F1`, `1`):

[image]

[image]

More information on the feature: [Locate a file in the Project tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#scroll_to_from_source).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use mouse but keyboard shortcut

- First option could be assigning a shortcut to `Select in Project View` may do the trick. It is located under `Keymap`/`Other`.
- Second option could be to install `Scroll From Source` plugin for this. The details are [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7606-scroll-from-source)

> Set the keyboard shortcut to the function of "Scroll From Source" in Project Panel. You can set the special shortcut by yourself to all OS(Window/Linux/Mac)

> Default shortcut is <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> for Mac.

Comment: Actually there is a built-in shortcut Alt+F1,1 (Windows, just hover over the symbol to see the shortcut)

Comment: When i looked for that feature (couple of years ago) it wasn’t available, since that i use same plugins, will check. @stefan.at.wpf

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf i just checked it opens a pop-up menu and then you select from it. But you may add a shortcut to `select in project view` which opens and selects it. (updated the answer)